# Download and save file to database using php

Tags: php, mysql, curl

I'm writing a program using php to download all picture with specified format and save them into my database (MySQL).

I'm using cURL but I can not get file (only send it to user browser).

Is there any another function or class that I can use to save file to database?

```
$ch=curl_init($_REQUEST["URL"]);
header("Content-type:" . curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE));
$txt=curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: You can too get it in a file. Tell cURL not to output the result, or use output buffering. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE).
This will make curl_exec return the file as astring instead of outputting it. This way you can save it to the database.

Read more: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Answer (score 2):

To get the downloaded file's content you need to set a [curl option](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) before you call `curl_exec()`:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to use the option CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER:

```
 $ch=curl_init($_REQUEST["URL"]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNSTRANSFER,true);
$txt=curl_exec($ch);
```

You could also use file_get_contents()

Comment: Thank you, but I want content type!!!<br> and I used <code>curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNSTRANSFER,true); </code> but it did not helped me!